# Problema ao extender a classe django.db.models.Manege

Tags: django

Eu estendi a classe `django.db.models.Manager` para pegar os registros que são `públicos` e ao fazer isso eu não consigo mais listar todos os registros chamando `Product.objects.all()`

Até na minha área de administração, somente são listadas os registros com status públicos. Os registros com status privados são ocultados.

o meu módel é

```
STATUS_PUBLISH = (
    ('público', 'pùblico'),
    ('privado', 'Privado'),
)

class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(status_publish='público')


class Product(TimeStampedModel):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    status_publish = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_PUBLISH, default='público')
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True, help_text='Separe as categorias com vírgula')

    publish = ProductManager()
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("gallery:product_update", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        return super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: "Até na minha áre de admin só aparece os registro com status 'público`". Essa afirmação vc diz que mesmo salvando a opção privado, o registro muda pra público, ou somente os que são salvos como público é q são apresentados?

Comment: Isso, somente os que são salvos como 'público' são exibidos. Os que são 'privados' não aparecem.

Answer (score 3):

Não entendi muito bem o que vc prentede fazer, mas se quiser listar tudo, é só não filtrar no Manager

```
class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().all()
```

se quiser listar separadamente, vc pode fazer 2 Managers (não sei se plural de manager escreve assim =P)

```
class ProductPublicoManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(status_publish='público')


class ProductPrivadoManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(status_publish='privado')



class Product(TimeStampedModel):
    
    [...todo o código]

    publico = ProductPublicoManager()
    privado = ProductPrivadoManager()
    objects = models.Manager()
    
    [... resto do código]
```

Comment: Ok! Tipo. Eu só criei o manager para não ter que ficar escrevendo o tempo todo `Product.objects.filter(status_publish='público')` e ao escrever esse maneger, eu não consigo mais listar todos os produtos.

Comment: não sei se vc testou, (então é só pra ser redundante mesmo) mas a ordem que vc coloca os *Manager* influencia na apresentação da área administrativa. Se colocar o ```objects = models.Manager()``` antes do ```publish = ProductManager()``` vc teria outro resultado.